# Sinatra routes regular expression alphanumeric

Tags: regex, sinatra

```
#get "/blog/:title-:slug" do
#  erb :"/blog/#{params[:slug]}.html
#end
```

both `:title` and `slug` can be alphanumeric.

I am trying to make the url dynamic with regular expression.

```
get '/blog/*-*' do
    erb :"/blog/#{params['splat'][1]}.html"
end
```

I came up with the version above which uses a wildcard and that works but I am hoping to make the route more specific. I am currently struggling with what I have below after consulting the ruby regexp documentation.

```
# get '/blog\/[[:alnum:]]/-/[[:alnum:]]/' do
#   puts params['alnum']
#   erb :"/blog/#{params['alnum']}.html"
# end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sinatra accepts regexp values as the parameter to route methods (`get`, `post` etc.), so the route can be rewritten as:

```
get %r{/blog/(\w+)-(\w+)} do
  ...
end
```

This will match all the routes that have alphabets or numbers. However, the captured values won't be available in the `params` object. To achieve that, you'd need to use the [named captures](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#named_captures-method) syntax:

```
get %r{/blog/(?<title>\w+)-(?<slug>\w+)} do
  puts params[:title]
  puts params[:slug]
end
```

you can also use the unicode-aware `[[:alnum:]]` regexp matcher:

```
get %r{/blog/(?<title>[[:alnum:]]+)-(?<slug>[[:alnum:]]+)} do
  puts params[:title]
  puts params[:slug]
end
```